# Error union sql query

Tags: mysql, sql

I obtain this error

```
 The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns
```

when i try to execute this query

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM `items` WHERE `tags` LIKE '%winner%' ESCAPE '!' UNION SELECT DISTINCT * FROM `lists` WHERE `tags` LIKE '%winner%' ESCAPE '!'
```

Thx

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.  The error is very clear; what you want to accomplish is not.

Comment: You don't need to do SELECT DISTINCT since UNION removes the duplicates anyway.

Comment: In a union statement you must ensure that both queries return the same number of fields

Comment: in your db the no of columns in items and lists are different and also there is no need for distinct as you have used union

Comment: The error message is blatantly obvious! How exactly can you be struggling with this? Run `SELECT DISTINCT * FROM items WHERE tags LIKE '%winner%' ESCAPE '!'` and count the columns. Then run `SELECT DISTINCT * FROM lists WHERE tags LIKE '%winner%' ESCAPE '!'` and count the columns. It is always ***much better practice*** to explicitly indicate what columns you want to include in your `SELECT` result sets.

Answer (score 3):

When you use UNION or UNION ALL, you must ensure that the number of columns in the queries are the same, for example:

```
SELECT Product_ID,Product
FROM Products
UNION
SELECT Product
FROM Orders
```

Will not work, as the two queries will not return the same number of columns. However:

```
SELECT Product_ID,Product
FROM Products
UNION
SELECT Order_ID,Product
FROM Orders
```

Will work, as the number of columns in each is the same.

I would get rid of 'SELECT *' in your query.

Answer (score 0):

Please specify columns name instead of "*" in sql.

Exp:
SELECT DISTINCT Col1, Col2, col3  FROM `items` WHERE `tags` LIKE '%winner%'
UNION 
SELECT DISTINCT Col1, Col2, col3  FROM `lists` WHERE `tags` LIKE '%winner%'